# user: ["This field is required."] in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to allow user to update the name of Lists they have created. However, when I attempt to POST the data I return the following error:

```
user: ["This field is required."]
```

I have racked my brain trying to solve this, hardcoded the username etc. but I keep turning up empty. I'd be grateful for some more expertise to assist me.

Here is my view:

```
class UpdateUserListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = UserListSerializer
        queryset = UserList.objects.all()

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            serializer_class = UserListSerializer

            if self.request.method == "POST":
                list_id = request.data.get('id')
                user = UserList(user=self.request.user.id)
                list_name = request.data.get('list_name')
                data = {'id':int(list_id), 'list_name': list_name}
                serializer = serializer_class(user, data=data)
                
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.update()

                    return Response({'status' : 'ok'}, status=200)
        
                else:
                    return Response({'error' : serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

And here is my serializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'list_name']
```

Comment: You may need to pass the `user` data while updating the record

Comment: eg:  `if serializer.is_valid(): serializer.update(user)` ?

Answer (score 0):

So actually you are trying to update with POST request, you have to check wheather your code had been reached inside this update function and if it is reaching there then you have to pass `partial=True` in update otherwise serailizer will try to validate all the required fields so for that you can change as :-

```
serializer = serializer_class(user, data=data, partial=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I am still getting the same error.